# In fabric.js, how to disable text items when importing an SVG from URL

Tags: fabricjs

Good day,

Wondering, for fabric.js, while in the process of importing an SVG, how can I programmatically set the 'selectable' to false for all text items, but allow the image items to remain selectable?

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(urlString, function(objects, options) {
   var group = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   canvas.add(group).centerObject(group).renderAll();
},
// set the 'selectable' values for each item
function(item, object) {
  // how do I tell if the item is a text or image?
  //psuedo code
  if (item is text) {
     object.selectable = false;
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Johnny

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set all text objects to selectable = false then just loop though all the objects on the canvas and then test the objects for their type with "obj.get('type')"

here is an example:

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
  if(obj.get('type') ==='text' || obj.get('type') ==='i-text') {
    obj.selectable = false; 
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyhmeyer/otc7pmru/11/)